# Make something unhoverable for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a addClass function that trigers on element hover
What I want to do is remove that class when you click on the element. However when you click on it it automatically adds the class again because it is hovered (and this is how you add this class).

So is there any way to stop elements hover from triggering for say 2 seconds?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: You could use a `setTimeout` inside hover to `addClass` after `x` seconds, but that `x` seconds can get annoying.

Comment: I know it's not what you asked for, but might something like this be better? After a click, the mouseenter code doesn't execute until after the mouse has left and reentered the element: http://jsfiddle.net/Ez4wR/

Comment: JasonP that is great. I think that would work. It is a shame that I just did something very similar and didn't think of it, but I am learning just now. How can I give you credit for your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a timeout when you mouseover the item. I also added a way for the timeout to clear itself if they get away from the item (not sure if you wanted that functionality or not)

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/uGkBs/)

```
var hoverTimeout;

$('.yourItem').on({
    'mouseover' : function() {
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() { 
            // do whatever
        }, 2000);
    },
    'mouseout' : function () {
        clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
    }    
});
```

Comment: That is very nice, but it also slows down the first hover, which I don't want.
However I will combine that and JasonP answer and hopefully get a nice result.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a `timeout` inside your `hover`

```
.hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        //code that takes place after 2 seconds 
    }, 2000);
}, ...
```

Comment: I think this will still add the class after 2 seconds. it doesn't block hover event